# Java 8 Conditional Filter | Lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-stream

```
    return userRepo
            .findAll()
            .stream()
            .filter(user -> user.getIsActive()==active)
            .filter(user -> user.getEyeColor().equalsIgnoreCase(eyeColor))
            .filter(user -> user.getBalance() >= balance.doubleValue())
            .filter(user -> user.getAge() >= age.intValue())
            .filter(user -> user.getAddress().getZip() == zipCode.intValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**How to skip filter row when, for example, eyeColor= null;**

Comment: `user -> eyeColor == null || ...`

Comment: @VLAZ- that wont work in fact that would cause exception.

Comment: @JoopEggen .. tried .. not working .. I want to skip the entire evaluation if possible

Comment: Ah, right - I thought it was the user's eye colour that is null. Well, in that case `if(eyeColor != null) stream.filter()`?

Comment: `user -> eyeColor != null && ...` - of course then the entire query is senseless

Comment: @JoopEggen the first one worked actually .. when I was trying I was mistakenly putting one =. thank you for correcting me.

Comment: No problem, nice seeing Stream.

Comment: @JoopEggen .. so theoretically, here as soon as it sees null - filter evaluation is exiting .. right ? I rechecked I was putting != null which was not working == null worked

Comment: `.filter(x -> true)` continues accepting every x, `.filter(x -> false)` rejects every x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207214/discussion-between-reverse-and-joop-eggen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credits to @Joop Eggen

```
return userRepo
    .findAll()
    .stream()
    .filter(user -> active == null || user.getIsActive() == active.booleanValue())
    .filter(user -> eyeColor == null || user.getEyeColor().equalsIgnoreCase(eyeColor))
    .filter(user -> user.getBalance() >= balance.doubleValue())
    .filter(user -> age == 0 || user.getAge() >= age)
    .filter(user -> zipCode == 0 || user.getAddress().getZip() == zipCode)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant solution in this case is to create your own `Predicate<User>` like the following

```
public class UserPredicate implements Predicate<User> {

    boolean active; String eyeColor; double balance; int age; int zipCode;

    public UserPredicate(boolean active, String eyeColor, double balance, int age, int zipCode) {
         // assign to variables
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(User user) {
        return isActive(user) && hasExpectedBalance(user) && hasExpectedAge(user) && hasExpectedZipCode(user);
    }

    // implement the methods user in test
    private isActive(User user) {
        return user != null && user.getActive() == this.active;
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Then in your code, use it like this:

```
return userRepo
        .findAll()
        .stream()
        .filter(new UserPredicate(active, eyeColor, balance.doubleValue(), age.intValue(), zipCode.intValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

The first filter should checked for an empty object. In your code there are two cases for this checking. You can do it by finding first null object and doing negation to stop next filtering.

```java
return userRepo
    .findAll()
    .stream()
    .filter(user -> ! Stream.of(user.getEyeColor(), user.getAddress()).anyMatch(Objects::isNull) )
    .filter(user -> user.getIsActive()==active)

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple condition as part of the filter
.filter(user -> (null == user.getEyeColor() || user.getEyeColor().equalsIgnoreCase(eyeColor)))